# user profile service application in sharePoint 2013

Tags: user-profile-service

how to perform a basic test in SharePoint 2013 to check if the user profile service application is running properly.

Answer (score 2):

their are couple of things you can check to make sure User Profile service is running.

- check if all users from AD( depending upon ur OU & filters) having a profile in the User Profile. Check from central Admin.
- Make Sure, User Profile and User Profile Sync service is up and running.
- click on the User's Profile and see if u are getting the correct information as it is in AD.
- On SharePoint User Profile Page at Central Admin, check if number of imported profiles meet with AD numbers.

Check last part of [this blog](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12545.sharepoint-2013-setting-up-user-profile-synchronization-12.aspx)